# Number of instruments used in GMM model (pgmm function in R)

Tags: r, instruments, gmm

I performed a GMM (Generalized Methods of Moments) analysis in R using the `pgmm` package.

I included additional external variables in my model. However, since the model also uses internal instruments (lagged dependent variables), I am not sure how many instruments there are in total.

Is there any way how I can calculate them or is there a function in R that provides the value?

Comment: Hi @Li4991, did you find an answer to this question?

Comment: Hi @user3227641, unfortunately not. I am still not sure how I can calculate the number of instruments used.

I know that there is an option in Stata to calculate the GMM model and Stata automatically shows the number of instruments used. But still: I am not sure how to receive the same functionalities / same information in R.

Comment: I discovered that estimating a GMM model using the pvargmm function from panelvar package reports the number of instruments. However, the downside of this option compared to the pgmm package is that, it is not possible, as far as I can see, to report autocorrelation test results.

Comment: @user3227641 - I tried using this function and package. However, it seems like it is not suitable for system GMM, since it only offers the transofrmation types "First-difference" or "forward orthogonal deviations".